Google credential manager for API 26
I try to setup Google Authentication using Credential Manager from Google. But when I write the code below it says that it works only for API 34 and above. Instead it looks like they recommend Google Sign.
But I also found that Google Sign-In option is deprecated and will be removed from SDK in 2025. What should I do than?
   val request:GetCredentialRequest = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
        .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
        .build()


stupid goddamn google, the guide is trash and they can't even provide correct code, lmao

val request: androidx.credentials.GetCredentialRequest = androidx.credentials.GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
            .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
            .build()

Please, use androidx.credentials instead of android.credentials.
Stupid Google should've mentioned the import.
